# Add a sound to android application

Tags: android

I want to add sound to my Android application using the following piece of code:

```
 mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.2lna zaman.mp3);
```

I have already imported MediaPlayer and declared an object of it `m` but the problem is when i 
write `(R.raw)` then there is no any choice called raw and underlined it by red line

Comment: u have raw folder in res ?

Comment: no but i have add it to project

Answer (score 3):

1. In name of audio there is space. Space is not allowed in name. Delete space.
2. And name also not start with digit so change it too. Rename file so that its start with alphabet.
3. Also no need of extension i.e `.mp3`. For example `mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);` after file name no need to write `.mp3`

Comment: Kanwaljit Singh please remove digit from file name :) dude i think u forgot to remove 2lna zaman.mp3

Answer (score 0):

Space is not allowed in name which we add in drawable try to remove space and try again later

```
 mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.lna_zaman.mp3);
```

u can add " _ " instead of space

Comment: it's not about spaces but there is no object called raw 
when i press . after R   (R.   ) no raw choice

Comment: @user3508462 Its obvious because its not identifying your raw file because its start with digit.

Comment: @BhanuSharma name not start with digit.

Comment: i have remove spaces and digits but still same problem

Comment: @user3508462 You have to rename file in raw folder too. Lets say change name of file to **test** then paste it into raw folder and change your code into **mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.test);**

Comment: yes drawable name should not start with digit, capital latter but if it is a prob then i think this is arrive while u try to compile itself i think your raw folder not able to find that file just try to add raw folder again and then add that music file and also clean and clear the app jusr chk what R file u include in app then it will automatically show in drop down when u write R.id